# Highchart Add text after value tooltip

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This link is an example for using group bar in Highchart:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/KWPsv/

```
series: [{
    name:'Total',
    groupPadding:.16,
    color:'rgba(204,204,204,.5)',
    grouping:false,
    data:[55,108,87,51,92]       
},{
    name:'Group 1',
    data: [7,12,16,32,64]
},{
    name:'Group 2',
    data: [16,32,64,7,12]
},{
    name:'Group 3',
    data: [32,64,7,12,16]
}]
```

for now, I want to add more text after each value in tooltip.

Example: Group 1: 7 (%) ...

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert the tooltip bit as shown below:

```
xAxis:{
    categories:['A','B','C','D','E'],
    lineColor:'#999',
    lineWidth:1,
    tickColor:'#666',
    tickLength:3,
    title:{
        text:'X Axis Title',
        style:{
            color:'#333'
        }
    }
},
--------------------------------------
tooltip: {
    formatter: function () {
        var s = '<b>' + this.x + '</b>';
        $.each(this.points, function () {
            s += '<br/>' + this.series.name + ': ' +
                this.y + '%';
        });
        return s;
    },
    shared: true
},
----------------------------------------
yAxis:{
    lineColor:'#999',
    lineWidth:1,
    tickColor:'#666',
    tickWidth:1,
    tickLength:3,
    gridLineColor:'#ddd',
    title:{
        text:'Y Axis Title',
        rotation:0,
        margin:50,
        style:{
            color:'#333'
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: It might still need some refinement.